# Linked Object (proxy) does not play actions in Blender Game Engine

Tags: game-engine, linked-data

I have two identical characters, with a test Idle action set, in blender game engine. Both plays in viewport, but when I run the game only the appended one plays it action.

This is halting my development since I would preferable use external .blend files containing characters etcetera so I can keep on developing/animating on a specific character.

Check out this video to better understand.

http://instagram.com/p/k7XjakI79x/

Comment: can you upload the blend file? Than I would not have to create a dummy scene just to test this.

Comment: can't it's my game I am working on. Bug reported. Could do a quikc .blend with some base mesh rigged. And use same base mesh as appended, and linked in local proxy. Anyways, I bug reported. Will do that simple .blend scene and attach to my bug report. Can give you link later, when I am back infront of my computer.

Comment: Apparently, [playing animations in separate files loaded via libload is not possible](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/how-to-use-playaction-on-libloaded-objects). Nobody here seems to know how to do it.