# How to use playAction() on libloaded objects in BGE?

Tags: python, animation, game-engine

I'm loading the file like this:

```
logic.LibLoad(logic.expandPath('//car.blend'), 'Scene', verbose=True, load_actions=True)
```

And I get my object (without using `addObject()` BTW, is it how it's done?) fine, I can basically do what I want with it. But I cannot seem to use its actions.

**And** at loading time I can **see** the action being loaded in the console output:

> SceneName: Scene
>   ActionName: Car.flipOver

This is how I start the action:

```
    name = "Car.flipOver"
    start = 1.0
    end = 10.0
    layer = 0
    priority = 1
    blendin = 1.0
    mode = logic.KX_ACTION_MODE_PLAY
    layerWeight = 0.0
    ipoFlags = 1
    speed = 1.0

    # (tests to see if the car is stuck)

    self.playAction(name, start, end, layer, priority, blendin, mode, layerWeight, ipoFlags, speed)
```

Not only the action does not play, I get no warning or error message of any kind! (at least when you omit the `load_action` parameter you get a fair "failed to load action").
Can somebody explain to me how one can access actions in externally loaded .blend files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem seems to be in the `playAction` arguments exactly in `ipoFlags = 1` it should be `ipoFlags = 0`

I have no idea why but this is what got it working at least in my test file